# Modified Version of the (A)GPL

Tags: gpl, dual-license

I'm trying to make a dual-license source-available software that allows copying of the software for the sole purpose of contributing to the original software, with the exception of the copyright holders, who are 5 or so people. I planned on doing that by modifying a copyleft license, stating that copies must be distributed with a very restrictive license that doesn't allow usage or distribution. I chose to use the AGPL for this, but it said in the preamble that people may not modify it. I have three questions:

1. How come MongoDB made the SSPL license, which is a modified version of the GPLv3?
2. Can I do what MongoDB did to make my own license based on the (A)GPL?
3. Is there a better license/license-combination for the purpose I listed above?

Comment: So the only way anyone can get a copy of this program simply for the purpose of running it is to get it from the rightsholders, ie, redistribution is not allowed unless the recipient also modifies it?

Comment: That does not sound like a question related to open source as by the definition of the OSI and by this board. I vote to close. Open-source software allows anyone to use the software for any purpose - based on certain conditions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about open source

Comment: The open-source-relevant bit is the question about modifying the GPL itself, and [we have already dealt with that](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/253/458).