# License as permissive as WTFPL but including a warranty disclaimer

Tags: license-recommendation, mit, wtfpl

I like publishing my software completely open source with no limitations (no contribution required, etc). I thought about using the [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/), but it lacks an MIT-like disclaimer:

> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
>   IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>   AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
>   OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
>   SOFTWARE.

<strike>I would really like to merge the WTFPL with the upper part of the MIT license so I have a license as permissive as the WTFPL but also with a disclaimer that I am not responsible for any use of it. I would modify the disclaimer so it doesn't contain the term "copyright holder" (as I don't want to hold any copyright). Would this be legally okay? In other words: Am I allowed to take parts of the MIT license, modify them and add them to the WTFPL license?</strike>

What other licensing possibilities do I have to guarantee complete freedom (**without required attribution or anything**) while making sure I'm not responsible for anything someone else does with my code (e.g. security issues that damage a companies infrastructure, etc.)?

**Edit:** Okay, obviously people don't like random new license texts. However, I would really like to know what alternatives exist that suite my needs.

Comment: What is your concern about just using MIT? Please don't mangle together your own custom licence, it's bad enough for open source users to deal with the normal ones.

Comment: I don't like that people who use my code must provide attribution. Kindly asking them to do so - yes, of course. Forcing them to do so - a no-go for me. Also it forces people to keep the same MIT license on my code, which in my opinion completely destroys the purpose of a permissive license.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create my own license by modifying an existing one?](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/230/can-i-create-my-own-license-by-modifying-an-existing-one)

Comment: @dimo414 Not anymore :)

Comment: See the CC0 in my answer which is IMHO what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It usually a bad idea to create a new FOSS license as this will create a new island of oddity and will most likely not help your project being more successful, to the contrary.

The MIT license itself is often called the ISC license and it has many many variants. So many that the actual authorship fades to grey in the darkness of times. It is also the result of the evolution of older licenses from which it borrowed part of its text. As such it is likely a collective work with not clearly defined authorship and an impossible to determine licensing for its own text. If you want to adapt it you can do so safely and none of these undefined authors may be ever blame you for that. But I will blame you for the reasons I explained above.

> What other licensing possibilities do I have to guarantee complete freedom (without required attribution or anything) while making sure I'm not responsible for anything someone else does with my code (e.g. security issues that damage a companies infrastructure, etc.)?

Consider the [zlib license](https://enterprise.dejacode.com/license_library/Demo/zlib/#license-text) which does not even require attribution and only requires to keep the license text in the source code only. It has a minimalist disclaimer.

And with even fewer conditions, consider the [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/legalcode): it has a proper disclaimer unlike the WTPFL and is really a proper public domain dedication that is even acceptable in countries that do not have such concept like Germany. But it does not have an explicit or implicit patent grant (nor do the zlib or bsd licenses IMHO)

Comment: Accepted for the CC0 :)

Comment: Island of oddity = license proliferation if I understand correctly

Comment: @Benni Creative Commons [recommends against](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ#May_I_apply_CC0_to_computer_software.3F_If_so.2C_is_there_a_recommended_implementation.3F) using the CC0 for software, most importantly because it [isn't OSI approved](https://opensource.org/faq/#cc-zero), mainly due to its patent clause.

Answer (score 4):

Try The Unlicense, it seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

https://unlicense.org/

Comment: FYI Unlicense has not yet been approved by the OCI (Open Source Initiative). See [the list of approved licenses](https://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical).

Comment: @FranklinYu That's incorrect. The [OSI includes the Unlicense in its list of approved licenses](https://opensource.org/license/unlicense/).

Comment: Summary of the Unlicense's key properties: https://choosealicense.com/licenses/unlicense/

Comment: @maxschlepzig You probably meant “that’s *no longer* correct” :) https://lists.opensource.org/pipermail/license-review_lists.opensource.org/2020-June/004890.html

Answer (score 2):

You could license your software under the Free Public License 1.0.0

https://tldrlegal.com/license/free-public-license-1.0.0#fulltext

Also possible would according to your description be this license:

https://tldrlegal.com/license/do-what-the-fuck-you-want-to-but-it's-not-my-fault-public-license-v1-(wtfnmfpl-1.0)#fulltext

although I don't know how established/legally sustainable it is.

Comment: I have literally no idea about law & licensing. Can anything happen to me if I license the software under the FPL, and someone experiences damage because of a bug or any other error I made while writing it?

Comment: I am not a lawyer. I would wait reactions from others as well. But it appears the FPL does have some recognition https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mil-oss/0mgXhmtYlFQ Although you would have to check whether the terms of the country that this post was made in/applys to also applies to your country.

Comment: Thank you very much for that link! Yeah, my comment was an expression of waiting for people who perhaps are lawyers or at least do have some more knowledge than me :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [MIT license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License). It does [not require users credit you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_and_open-source_software_licenses), only that the license text and any associated copyright marks be maintained. That is *no burden* for users, and a minimal burden for anyone redistributing your code.

Remember also that you can always re-license something you own the copyright to in the future, so if you discover the MIT license is a burden for any of your users (hint: you won't) you can [work with them to select a different license](https://choosealicense.com/).

The world of software licenses is complicated enough already, and crafting your own "clever" license just burdens your users - they have to carefully read your license now to make sure there aren't any issues, whereas if you simply [use a standard license](http://ben.balter.com/2016/08/01/why-you-shouldnt-write-your-own-open-source-license/) it's immediately clear whether their intended use case will be acceptable.

Comment: `It does not require users credit you, only that the license text and any associated copyright marks be maintained with the source code.` Maintaining the associated copyright marks is giving credit, so the MIT license does require users credit you.

Comment: But licensees don't have to redistribute or acknowledge usage of the library unless they choose to. Compliance is passive.

Comment: That's not true. `The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software` If you distribute software licensed under the MIT license, you must include the copyright notice and permission notice from the MIT license. It only applies to unchanged MIT licensed code, but you still need to include it.

Comment: Right, but since the notice comes with the code, you're automatically compliant. You'd have to actively remove the licence or notice in order to violate the license. And that only applies to redistributing the code, not using it. I agree it's more restrictive than public domain, but it's not *burdensome*.

Comment: I'm simply advocating for defaulting to MIT rather than some made up license. If you have a concrete concern with MIT for a specific project that's one thing, but avoiding it out of fear makes your code harder for others to use safely, not easier.

Comment: I agree that it's not burdensome, but this answer contains factually wrong information. Even if you don't distribute the source code, you still need to include the copyright notices and permission notice if you're using any MIT licensed source code. The MIT license uses the word "Software", which includes both source code and binary formats.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I've tweaked the language, feel free to make further edits if you still don't think it's accurate. My intent is simply to discourage [license proliferation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/License_proliferation).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few well established licenses that are basically equivalent to the WTFPL plus a warranty disclaimer, you can choose from:

- [Unlicense](https://unlicense.org/) - [OSI approved](https://opensource.org/license/unlicense/) - cf. [choosealicense.com](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/unlicense/)
- [0BSD - Zero-Clause BSD](https://opensource.org/license/0bsd/) - [OSI approved](https://opensource.org/license/0bsd/)
- [MIT-0 - MIT No Attribution](https://opensource.org/license/mit-0/) - [OSI approved](https://opensource.org/license/mit-0/)

---

Note that although the [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/) is a fine public-domain-equivalent license, its [creators explicitly](https://creativecommons.org/2011/04/15/using-cc0-for-public-domain-software/) [recommend](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-apply-a-creative-commons-license-to-software) [against using it for software](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/CC0_FAQ#May_I_apply_CC0_to_computer_software.3F_If_so.2C_is_there_a_recommended_implementation.3F):

> Yes, CC0 is suitable for dedicating your copyright and related rights in computer software to the public domain, to the fullest extent possible under law. Unlike CC licenses, which should not be used for software, CC0 is compatible with many software licenses, including the GPL. However, CC0 has not been approved by the Open Source Initiative and does not license or otherwise affect any patent rights you may have. You may want to consider using an approved OSI license that does so instead of CC0, such as GPL 3.0 or Apache 2.0.

The OSI cites [concerns about the CC0's language on patents](https://opensource.org/faq/#cc-zero) as main reason for not approving it.

---

See also [Wikipedia's Public-domain-equivalent license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-domain-equivalent_license) page.

Comment: Just use 0BSD: it's older than the Unlicense but doesn't even mention the Public Domain while be it's equivalent. It's short and clear and based on well known BSD. It's used by Google in the Android sources (Toybox).